# Databrick csv cannot find local file

Tags: csv, databricks

In a program I have csv extracted from excel, I need to upload the csv to hdfs and save it as parquet format, doesn't matter with python version or spark version, no scala please.

Almost all discussions I came across are about databrick, however, it seems cannot find the file, here is the code and error:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema","true").option("delimiter",",").load("file:///home/rxie/csv_out/wamp.csv")
```

Error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/rxie/csv_out/wamp.csv
>   does not exist

The file path:

```
ls -la /home/rxie/csv_out/wamp.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 rxie linuxusers 2896878 Nov 12 14:59 /home/rxie/csv_out/wamp.csv
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue now!

The reason why it errors out of ***file not found*** is actually correct, because I was using Spark Context with setMaster("***yarn-cluster***"), that means all worker nodes will look for the csv file, of course all worker nodes (except the one starting the program where the csv resides) do not have this file and hence error out. What I really should do is to use ***setMaster("local")***.

FIX:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('test').setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
csv = "file:///home/rxie/csv_out/wamp.csv"
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema","true").option("delimiter",",").load(csv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, the file should be present at all worker nodes.
well. you can still read a local file in yarn cluster mode. you just need to add your file using addFile.

```
spark.sparkContext.addFile("file:///your local file path ")
```

spark will copy the file to each node where executor will be created and can be able to process your file in cluster mode as well.
I am using spark 2.3 version so you can change your spark context accordingly but addFile method remains same.

try this with your yarn (cluster mode) and let me know if it works for you.